# CSS reset values on Media Query Breakpoint (Resize window or Orientation changes)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am building a web app that has a fixed positioned Sidenav bar on Desktop **always** visible but on Mobile the Sidenav is hidden and the user clicks the Hamburguer button to Show it as modal and of course Close it later (Using Javascript for that).

**The Problem**

Lets imagine an iPad, that Vertically display mobile view but Horizontally displays the desktop view. If the user is Vertically and he toggles the Sidenav Visible and then Hidden, but if later he changes the orientation to Horizontal the Sidenav will be hidden, and the expected behaviour is that on desktop the Sidenav is always visible (I think this is because CSS Styles are loaded on page render, and when I change the styles with JS to toggle visibility it remains that way even when the DOM resized).

**Question**

The solution that occurred to me is having 2 identical Sidenavs and 1 show only on desktop and 1 only on mobile, and that way the styles of 1 dont affect the other, but that means a duplicated code.

If I want a more elegant solution without duplicating a whole block of code, I wonder if there is a way to reset all CSS values when it detects a Media Query Breakpoint, or what could be another solution?

I hope I explained well, and thank you for you help.

**Edit: Solution I found thanks tacoshy's comment**

When the Resize Event detects the Breakpoint it forces to trigger the Hide/Show function for the Sidenav

```
  const showDrawer = () => {
    var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
    var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');

    drawerBack.style.opacity = "1";
    drawer.style.left = "0";
    drawerBack.style.visibility = "visible"
  }

  const hideDrawer = () => {
      var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
      var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');
  
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "0";
      drawer.style.left = "-16rem";
      setTimeout(
          () => {drawerBack.style.visibility = "hidden"}
          , 500);
  }

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFunction);

  const resizeFunction = () => {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
    var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');
    if (w > 1216) {
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "1";
      drawer.style.left = "0";
      drawerBack.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "0";
      drawer.style.left = "-16rem";
      setTimeout(
        () => {drawerBack.style.visibility = "hidden"}
        , 500);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can also define media queries not only depending on screen-size but on landscape or portaite mode. You can do an open and clsoe of the sidebar withotu JS with input field checkbox as well as doing animations of it with pure HTML and CSS. Last but not least do the display styling right as inline style. You can do the styliny by adding and removing a class that is written within media queries...

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found thanks tacoshy's comment

When the Resize Event detects the Breakpoint it forces to trigger the Hide/Show function for the Sidenav

```
  const showDrawer = () => {
    var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
    var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');

    drawerBack.style.opacity = "1";
    drawer.style.left = "0";
    drawerBack.style.visibility = "visible"
  }

  const hideDrawer = () => {
      var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
      var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');
  
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "0";
      drawer.style.left = "-16rem";
      setTimeout(
          () => {drawerBack.style.visibility = "hidden"}
          , 500);
  }

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFunction);

  const resizeFunction = () => {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
    var drawerBack = document.querySelector('.drawer-back');
    if (w > 1216) {
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "1";
      drawer.style.left = "0";
      drawerBack.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      drawerBack.style.opacity = "0";
      drawer.style.left = "-16rem";
      setTimeout(
        () => {drawerBack.style.visibility = "hidden"}
        , 500);
    }
  }
```